# Rspec which actually tests method with instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a service method as

```
class Service
  def maximum_match
    max = @hash.values.max
    Hash[@hash.select { |_k, v| v == max }]
  end
end
```

My test is like

```
context 'Finding tags count' do    
    it 'counts tags and returns maximum match' do      
      service = Service.new     
      expect(service.maximum_match).to eq some_result
    end
  end
```

How can I pass any values `@hash` to run my test?

Error is `NoMethodError:undefined method 'values' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Well, you have to pass / set `@hash` somewhere. How would you use / call the method outside of RSpec?

Comment: BTW, [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) already returns a hash. Wrapping the result in `Hash[...]` is superfluous.

Comment: Within service `@hash` will have some values assigned from another method. How can I pass/set `@hash` within my test?

Comment: @Ninja: call that other method in your test to setup your `@hash`. You can set it directly with `instance_variable_set`, but then you risk decoupling your test from reality.

Comment: Yeah that will work but i want to test specifically this method by passing random `@hash` values. Input is unpredictable here.

Comment: @Ninja this could be an indication that `Service` is missing a method that allows you to set `@hash` from the outside. I'd say pass the hash to `Service.new` so you don't have an undefined state in the first place.

Comment: testing should lead to good design. if it's hard to test something, the design is usually bad. make sure to change your code to be testable with ease.

Answer (score 2):

Ninja, you can use `service.instance_variable_set(@hash, your_value)` right above the `expect` line

[source](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)